# Did Coinbase discontinue their API Access or just Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

Got a letter from Coinbase:

```
Hi there,
```

> Thank you for contacting Coinbase Support and our apologies for the
>   delay in responding.
>
> As of August 22nd, it was decided that functionality for all Oauth
>   applications, both approved applications and those pending approval,
>   would be disabled as we can no longer provide support for these
>   applications.
>
> We understand that this may be frustrating, especially with regards to
>   the lack of communication over the disabling, but it was a decision
>   that we had to make due to the change in levels of support that we can
>   provide.
>
> At the moment it is not definitive if Oauth applications disabling
>   will be permanent, but if there are any changes, those changes will be
>   communicated.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience that this causes, and we appreciate
>   your understanding.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Coinbase Support

Anyone get  this  letter? What are others  using?

Comment: I have the same issue. Oauth is nto working anymore :/ What makes me really angry is that they did this without notice and the webiste still shows the option to use oauth.

Comment: I was in dev and went with Oauth2, which took me a lot of time to get the sauce just right to actually work, list all accounts, etc. The documentation said to use Oauth2 and not the API. So  are the apps like MINT still ok because  they use the API Key access?

Comment: All the apps/users that are currently linked will remain linked . For some reason if they unlink/disconnect then they won't be able to login again.
From now on only API is available, no more thirdparty.

Also, GDAX is now unsupported, all the calls will have to change the url